# Is there a way to define a field in JSON Schema to have a enum of string or other arbitrary string values?

Tags: json, jsonschema

The reason is we have a field , most time it should be an enum of string, but at certain time, the enum might not cover all the cases. So we allow user to send any other string if their value are not in the enum.
In this way we actually reminder users they can pass the value in the enum or pass their own values. I can add some doc or description. But just want to see if there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, and it's even called `enum` :). https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/generic.html#enumerated-values

If you're not sure what the list of values are, but you have that defined somewhere else, you can bring it in with a reference, e.g.:

```
{
  "properties": {
    "my_property": {
      "$ref": "http://example.com/some_schema.json#/definitions/my_enum"
    }
  }
}

{
  "$id": "http://example.com/some_schema.json",
  "definitions": {
    "my_enum": {
      "enum": [ "list..", "of..", "values.." ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your case, could it be possible to have two fields; one enum and one 'open-ended' string ?

This way you can use the 'OneOf' to pick the enum or the string like this:

```
    "oneOf" : [{
        "properties" : {
            "firstName" : {
                "type" : "string"
            },
            "lastName" : {
                "enum" : [ "ing", "tech", "customer" ]
            }
```